# VBA Word.Selection.Copy not working correctly

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a problem I can't seem to wrap my head around. I'm trying to populate a UserForm using Shapes (Images) from a Word-Document. I use this code to do so:

```
iShapeCount = wrdDoc.Shapes.Count
i = 0

If iShapeCount > 0 Then

    ReDim oPic(iShapeCount - 1) As IPictureDisp

        For Each wrdShape In wrdDoc.Shapes
            With wrdShape
                wrdDoc.Activate
                .Select
                wrdAppMain.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy
                Set oPic(i) = PastePicture(lPicType)
        End With

        i = i + 1

        Next wrdShape

End If
```

With oPic being a one-dimentional Array of Pictures and PastePicture being the Subroutine to get the copied Image off of the Clipboard and into the Array as an Image-File.

So far so good.

This works exactly like it should, but as soon as there are more than two Shapes (Images) present in the Word-Document, the Copy-Command copies the first two like a charm, but all other ones (although correctly selected) will not be copied with the Copy-Command copying literally NOTHING.

Another funny thing: If I leave out the `wrdAppMain.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy`-thingy and manually Ctrl-C the Shape selected by the Programm as it goes through the loop, it works no matter how many Shapes there are in the Word-Document.

So you see: I'm at the end of my rope here. Please help :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried debugging step by step? if yes, redo it and each time it jumps to the if statement control the value of i (moving over i with the mouse while debugging) . What results do you get?

Comment: Hi Kathara! i goes from 0 to 6 as intended (7 Images in this case). Problem is rather that as it goes to three the Selection.Copy-Command does not copy, so the PastePicture-Subroutine fills the rest of the Array with Nothings.

Comment: why don't you try to copy the shape directly?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just give the shape to the oPic-Array?

```
iShapeCount = wrdDoc.Shapes.Count

If iShapeCount > 0 Then

    ReDim oPic(iShapeCount - 1) As IPictureDisp

    For i = 0 to (iShapeCount -1)
        For Each wrdShape In wrdDoc.Shapes
            oPic(i) = wrdShape
        Next wrdShape
    Next i

End If
```

oPic would be declared as Variant.

Comment: Yeah. It surely works. But the problem that results from this, is that when populating the userform I seem to need an ImageFile. So if I fill in the Shapes directly without converting, it will give me a "Types don't match"-Exception here: 

`Set allImages(i) = OrderWindow.Controls.Add("Forms.Image.1", "Thumbnail" & i)
allImages(i).Picture = **currentImage**`
with currentImages being the Shapes we populated oPic with.

Comment: Ok. Instead of "oPic(i) = wrdShape" could you try "Set oPic(i) = PastePicture(wrdShape)" (although I must say, I'm not sure how PastePicture works >.<)

Comment: Haha. I don't know either exactly. Copied it myself off the Internet, but it works nicely. PastePicture does collect the current Data from the Clipboard, checks it, and if it matches, it creates an ImageFile from that very raw Data. So the Shapes itself Need to be in the Clipboard for the subroutine to be able to fetch it. I'll give it a try to make it so that it works with the shapes directly. I'll Report back as soon as I failed ;)

Comment: Hahaha, ok then I'll  wait for some feedback and for the time for me to help again ^.^ good luck anyway

Comment: HA! Couldn't get the PastePicture to work but I found a dirty way around it! I'll just save the Word-Document as HTML, so Word creates a Folder with all the Images in it. Then i can load those into oPic and delete the Folder again. Maybe a bit messy, but I can live with it ;)

Comment: If it works for you then that's ok, as it was you asking the question. :) And you can always make it better if you want :)

Comment: and a tipp that I got from a lot of comments: try to avoid .Select/.Selection and so on. VBA can run the code even when something is not selected directly in the Workbook... :)

Comment: Yes i can! But I wasted too much time on this thing, that in my opinion should work! ;)...Thanks for the help though. I'll consider the tipp on future endeavors!

Comment: @hans_h because of the Q and A nature of this site. Please can you post your solution as an Answer for knowledge sharing continues. Happy that you got your answer and that you figured it out yourself.